# Looking for the title of a book (possibly by Stanislaw Lem)

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a certain sci-fi book. If I knew who the author was I wouldn't be asking this question but it might be a story by Stanislaw Lem. But I went through a list of his works and didn't find it there.
As I seem to recall the story, it's about a boy whose father returns from a mission in space. The boy suspects that the man who returned isn't his actual father and he tries to unmask him.
It's a vague description of a story that might have been written over and over again (I don't know :D). But I would appreciate if someone could help me find the title!

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Sounds more like Ray Bradbury

Comment: I've found it, I was looking for "The Fther-thing' by Philip K. Dick. On its wiki page the resemblance to Ray Bradbury stories is also mentioned! Thanks K Dog!